# How is it called, when you rhyme two words, one of which is transformed?

Tags: rhymes

Comedian [Hannibal Buress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hannibal_Buress) once [rhymed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9B7BQWnZJs) *“Morpheus”* with *“seashells by the seashorfeus”* (see also [full text](http://genius.com/4807965/Hannibal-buress-morpheus/Morpheus-walruses-seashells-by-the-seashorpheus)). The latter phrase references a [tongue-twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister) that goes [*“she sells seashells by the seashore”*](http://www.shelfari.com/characters/Tongue--twister-written-by-Terry-Sullivan-in-1908-and-inspired-by-Mary-Anning).

Buress deliberately changed the ending of the word *“seashore”*, so it could rhyme with *“Morpheus”*. Is there a name for this particular rhyme? If not, to which more general class this kind of rhyme could belong? Wikipedia's [types of rhymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme#Types_of_rhyme) doesn't list anything similar.

If there's no name for that kind of rhyming, what are similar examples of such rhyming?

Comment: Deliberately modifying words for the *sake* of rhymes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a species of ***[forced rhyme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forced_rhyme),*** although that term is [also used](http://www.poems-and-quotes.com/discussion/topic.html?topic_id=133399) for any rhyme for the sake of which normal word order, scansion, or diction have been unduly sacrificed.

The type of forced rhyme exemplified by the questioner’s quotation from Buress is particularly tempting when one is attempting trisyllabic rhyme, which works out rather well as both tend to humor. Thus W. S. Gilbert, in [the Major-General’s self-introductory number in *The Pirates of Penzance*](https://math.boisestate.edu/gas/pirates/web_op/pirates13.html), coins the hitherto unheard-of adjectives *animalculous* (to rhyme with *calculus),* *parabolous* (to rhyme with *Heliogabalus),* and *adventury* (to rhyme with *century)*—and further perpetrates *lot o’ news* to rhyme with *hypotenuse,* and *heard the music’s din afore* to rhyme with *Pinafore.*

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[poetic licence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/poetic-licence)*** is a generic but appropriate expression  for this kind of  unusual practices:

> - the ​act by a ​writer or ​poet of ​changing ​facts or ​rules to make a ​story or ​poem more ​interesting or ​effective.

(Cambridge Dictionary)